# Can VirtualBox run operating systems designed for ARM processors?

Tags: virtualbox, arm, x86

For example, can I run Android, which is mostly run on ARM processors, run on VirtualBox on x86 Intel processors?

I am aware of Android x86, however, that is not a viable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [VirtualBox Wiki: Status: Guest OSes](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) and [Getting Support for Oracle VM VirtualBox](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/support/index.html).

But there are Android emulators available e.g. as part of [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html).

ARM is fundamentally different from x86. It would need to emulate the entire CPU which is something VirtualBox currently doesn't do.